# Outlook Web AddIn not working when started via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have been recently trying to create a new web add in for microsoft outlook. I am completely new to this. I have followed the documentation from microsoft and created a new simple web add in for outlook. My addin has a CustomTab that contains 6 controls (buttons). Here is the code for the manifest file:

```
<Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <!-- Message Read -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
                <CustomTab id="myTab">
                    <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                    <Group id="NoraGroup">
                        <Label resid="NoraGroupLabel" />
                        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1">
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                            </Action>
                        </Control>

                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button2">
                            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                <FunctionName>saveEmail</FunctionName>
                            </Action>
                        </Control>

                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3">
                            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                <FunctionName>saveEmailAndAttachment</FunctionName>
                            </Action>
                        </Control>
                        <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                    </Group>
                </CustomTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
```

Attached is the screenshot as to how the addin worked before:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsZuY.png)

But now, when I run the addin from Visual studio, the main button NoRA is displayed. But when I click it, the list of controls are not displayed.

Here is a screenshot of the console debug when I load the addin using Visual studio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGJVC.png)

Comment: Do you see your commands on the ribbon in Outlook?

Comment: No. When outlook is loaded, only the main button "NoRA" is visible (marked red in the screenshot in question). When I click this button, nothing happens. In short, the menu with all the command buttons is not displayed. Interesting point is that, when I start outlook 365 without visual studio, the commands are displayed and work. But they use an outdated javascript file (where command actions lie) that I last edited 3 weeks ago. I made some changes to the javascript file yesterday and tried to debug with visual studio. Unfortunately, the commands are not visible anymore.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the office cache before running your add-in?

Comment: Yes, I clear the cache everytime I run into trouble. I have just tested my addin again. It works when I start outlook addin without visual studio (the changes from javascript file can now be seen). But when I start the outlook addin from visual studio, I can see the button but nothing happens when I click on it. I noticed in the dev tools console tab something strange "Manifest: Line:1, column:1, Syntax error." I want to debug the addin using Visual studio for further development.

Answer (score 0):

> but they use an outdated javascript file (where command actions lie) that I last edited 3 weeks ago. I made some changes to the javascript file yesterday and tried to debug with visual studio. Unfortunately, the commands are not visible anymore.

The very first thing is to clear the Office cache. See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information.